# woocommerce paypal standard transaction id

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

Hello I am using woocommerce and need to find the paypal transaction id, as I found in the forums, I can get the transaction id with `get_post_meta($order->id, '_transaction_id', true)` . But when I am testing the paypal with sandbox, it doesn't work. Is that because I am using a sandbox account? will it work for a real account? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sandbox wouldn't have anything to do with that. When an order is created in Woo it would save the transaction ID either way, assuming you complete the PayPal transaction. So we need to know what exactly you mean when you say you tried it and it doesn't work.  What code did you try, and where did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing inside my localhost, uploaded the files to the hosting and everything started working. Thanks